# open java FX application from another java FX class

Tags: java, class, javafx, fxml

I have two Java classes. Let's take it as A & B

I have a **Label B1** in class A and when I click '**B1**', I want the next java FX class to be opened.

I tried using this code, but it throws a series of exceptions and I couldn't achieve the task.

> CLASS A :

```
label.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
           Application.launch( B.class );
        }
    });
```

> CLASS B :

```
 public class B extends Application{
 public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    VBox vb = new VBox();
    Label sub = new Label("TEST");
    primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
    Scene scene = new Scene(vb, 630, 500);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    vb.getChildren().addAll(sub);
    primaryStage.show();
 }
}
```

P.S.

I am not using FXML to add style to the scenes.

Comment: Why do you have more than one `Application` class in a single application? The `Application` represents the application. The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html#launch-java.lang.String...-) explicitly states that you can't call `launch()` more than once.

Comment: I have two classes inside the same java package which are nothing but two FX apps. I want to load class B from A  @James_D

Comment: you can not do that, this `Application.launch( B.class );` can only be called once do you have access or can you control the other javafx application?

Comment: Is it possible if i create a new inner class with another stage and then I load it ??